# Sizing a flash tank

Tags: steam, boilers, multiphase-flow

I have to size a vertical flash tank that is located on the blowdown line of a steam generator.

General data:

- Steam generator pressure: 15 bars
- Blowdown flow rate: 1 t/h of water at 198°C
- Pressure in the flash tank: 1.1 bar
- % of flash steam forming in the flash tank: 18,4%
- Average mass and volume of flash steam at 100°C: 184 kg/h - 286 m3/h
- Max instantaneous steam volume flow rate: 9 m3/s
- Average mass and volume of water at ~100°C: 816 kg/h - 0.85 m3/h

I am not sure what to do next to size my tank. I know that there is a recommanded speed for the flash steam to evaporate without droplets of water, but I don't know this value. I think it is a bit less than 1 m/s if I am not mistaking.

I would tend to determine the diameter of the tank according to that speed but the issue is that the instantaneous volume flow rate of steam is quite huge. Considering a speed of 1 m/s, the diameter would be 3.4 meters.

Regarding the height, should I determine it according to water volume in order to avoid overflow?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Doesn't the ASME boiler code have some guidelines after writing rules for about 140 years ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with ASME. I will make some research to learn more about it